# In Pytest, Is there a way to "mock" or prevent something from happening while collecting test?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

So assume the allowing :

```
# services/foo.py

from apps.bar import BarClass

static_foos = BarClass().get_statics()

class FooService() :
     ....
```

and test code looking like :

```
# tests/test_foo.py

from services.foo import FooService

def test_foo_something() :
    assert FooService.something() == True
```

So here, when the pytest collects the test, it seems like it executes `BarClass.get_statics()` even before any of my attempts to mock or block access in `conftest.py` to kick in.

To be more specific, assuming `get_statics()` has some `requests.get` in it, a typical way of blocking network in pytest, which is mocking `socket.socket`, is not working.

From my knowledge, the only way to do something before tests get collected is to use `pytest_configure` in `conftest.py`, but also AFAIK it doesn't allow me to mock meaning that I'm just completely losing hope right now (Also it's not like I can really change the content of `test_something` for various reasons).

Is there any possible solution in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can import `BarClass` from `apps.bar` right before importing `FooService` and mock the `get_statics`. For example:

```
from apps.bar import BarClass

def do_nothing(*args, **kwargs):
    pass

BarClass.get_statics = do_nothing

from services.foo import FooService

def test_foo_something() :
    assert FooService.something() == True
```

However I think it would be better to add some initializing function to `services.foo` and call it when its needed. Something like:

```
from apps.bar import BarClass

static_foos = None

def init():
    static_foos = BarClass().get_statics()

class FooService():
    ...
```

Comment: I did contact the owner of `services.foo` and asked if i could do something similar to adding a init for it. The way it was coded was something related to how get_statics() shouldn't be called multiple times since it was fairly heavy task. Ended up doing some singleton-like initializer and the situation is now under control

Answer (score 2):

You can import the `services.foo` module within the test function instead, *after* you monkey-patch `requests.get`:

```
import requests

# define your MockResponse class here

def test_foo_something(monkeypatch):
    def mock_get(*args, **kwargs):
        return MockResponse()

    monkeypatch.setattr(requests, "get", mock_get)
    from services.foo import FooService

    assert FooService.something() == True
```